# jquery - bug with displaying select options

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select menus where the pattern is :

```
<select name='device$num' id='device$num' size='8' multiple='multiple' >"
```

I want to display the values out when any one of these select changes.

I tried this but sometimes I get undefined values from the alert. what is wrong?

```
<script>
    \$("select[id^=device]").change(function () {
        \$("#paramselection").html(" ");
        \$("#voltageselection").html(" ");

        // IF THE DATA HAS CHANGED, FIND OUT WHICH DATA SECTIONS ARE STILL VALID

        \$("select[id^=device] :selected").val(function(index, value) {
            alert(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another question, how do i pattern match such that id^=device\d+? Sorry, I am more familar with perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid redundant DOM selection, cache the `device` elements, and use that to get the selected values of all of them

From the `devices` set, use [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with the [`selected-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to get the selected `<option>` elements.

Then use [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create a jQuery object containing the values, then [`get()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to retrieve the Array from the object.

```
  // cache all the "device" elements as you assign the "change" handler
var devices = $("select[id^=device]").change(function () {
    $("#paramselection").html(" ");
    $("#voltageselection").html(" ");

         // from the "devices" variable, find selected options, and
         //    create an Array of the values
    var selected = devices.find('option:selected')
                          .map(function(){
                              return this.value;
                          }).get();

    alert( selected ); // will alert an array of the selected values
});
```

Comment: Hi tried the coding and it works for one section. However, I want to alert all the values that are currently selected by the user... so i tried var selected = $("select[id^device]").val(); but this doesn't work..

Comment: @Gordon: I misunderstood. I'll update in a few minutes. EDIT: Answer has been updated.

Comment: thanks patrick, also thanks for the links where I can study the examples

Answer (score 1):

Change your alert to this to get the selected text:

```
\$("select[id^='device'] option:selected").each(function() {
     alert($(this).text());
  });
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes in the selector.